# How to capture the selected cell value in tksheet with mouse click?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, event-handling

I'm working with the tksheet library in Python and I'm trying to capture the value of a cell when it is selected by the user with a mouse click. I've tried using the `<<CellSelect>>` event, but I'm having trouble retrieving the selected cell's value.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to properly capture the selected cell value in tksheet when it is clicked with the mouse?

I attempted to capture the value of a cell in a tksheet when it's selected by the user with a mouse click. For this, I used the `<<CellSelect>>` event in the tksheet library in Python.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official document on 
[Bind various table functionality to your own functions](https://github.com/ragardner/tksheet/wiki/Version-6#bind-various-table-functionality-to-your-own-functions), you can use `.extra_bindings()` to get what you need:

```py
# 'sheet' is an instance of tksheet.Sheet()

def on_cell_select(event):
    cell_value = sheet.get_cell_data(event.row, event.column)
    print(cell_value)

sheet.enable_bindings()
sheet.extra_bindings("cell_select", on_cell_select)
```